# Read Longitude and Lagitude from photo taken on Windows phone 7 Samsung

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone, silverlight-4.0

How can I read Longitude and Lagitude from photo taken on Windows phone 7 Samsung?

Answer (score 1):

According to following Windows Phone 7 forum post by Mark Chamberlain it seems to be not possible because the geolocation information is excluded from the EXIF for privacy reasons:

- [Latitude & Longitude info from photo taken by CameraCaptureTask](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/79319/480578.aspx)

> According to internal email correspondence, geolocation information is excluded from the EXIF for privacy reasons, even if your app is already setup with the users' consent for using the location service.